# How to display additional features

Tags: geotools

In my application I have a gis file to render an (java BufferedImage) image of countries with geotools which is sent directly to the browser. The colours of the countries (plus name and additional icons) are derived from the database. Depending on the database values, different rules and visualizers are applied to the Features from the gis file.

```
public BufferedImage renderOverviewImage(FileDataStore dataStore) {

    FeatureSource featureSource = dataStore.getFeatureSource();
    ContentFeatureCollection featureCollection = (ContentFeatureCollection) featureSource.getFeatures();
    SimpleFeatureIterator sfi = featureCollection.features();
    Map<FeatureId, PojoType> featureIdMap = new HashMap<FeatureId, PojoType>();

    BoundingBox boundingBox = null;

    try {
        while (sfi.hasNext()) {
            SimpleFeature simpleFeature = sfi.next();

            // this part here is actually a bit more complicated, the map will be enriched
            // with pojos which determine the eventual colour
            PojoType pojo = gatherInformationFromDatabase(simpleFeature);
            featureIdMap.put(simpleFeature.getIdentifier(), pojo);
        }
    } finally {
        sfi.close();
    }

    // Create a map context and add our shapefile to it
    MapContent map = new MapContent();

    // Create a basic Style to render the features
    Style mapStyle = createMapStyle(featureIdMap);

    // Add the features and the associated Style object to
    // the MapContext as a new MapLayer
    map.layers().clear();
    Layer someLayer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, mapStyle);
    map.addLayer(someLayer);

    boundingBox = map.getMaxBounds();

    BufferedImage image = renderImage(map, 600, boundingBox);
    map.dispose();

    return image;

}

private Style createMapStyle(Map<FeatureId, PojoType> featureIdMap) {

    List<Rule> ruleList = new ArrayList<Rule>();

    for (FeatureId featureId : featureIdMap.keySet()) {
        Rule rule;
        PojoType pojo = featureIdMap.get(featureId);

        // create a partially opaque outline stroke
        Stroke stroke = styleFactory.createStroke(filterFactory.literal(outlineColor), filterFactory.literal(1), filterFactory.literal(0.5));

        // create a partial opaque fill
        Fill fillstyleFactory.createFill(filterFactory.literal(fillColor), filterFactory.literal(0.5));

        PolygonSymbolizer polygonSym = styleFactory.createPolygonSymbolizer(stroke, fill, null);
        Rule rule = styleFactory.createRule();
        rule.symbolizers().add(polygonSym);


        // add other symbolizers here...

        // tie this rule to the featureId
        rule.setFilter(ff2.id(featureId));
        ruleList.add(rule);

    }

    FeatureTypeStyle fts = styleFactory.createFeatureTypeStyle(ruleList.toArray(new Rule[] {}));
    Style style = styleFactory.createStyle();
    style.featureTypeStyles().add(fts);

    return style;
}
```

Now I need to add geo-referenced icons to the image map. The coordinates are also stored in the database.

Setting the AnchorPoint does not help because the anchorpoint is only a point within the rendered image.

The comments in org.geotools.styling.Graphic class say:
"The 'hot spot' to use for positioning the rendering at a point must either be inherent from the external format or be defined to be the  "central point" of the graphic."

Is it possible to add a PointVisualizer with Graphic and then set the location coordinates for it? Or would I have to create artificial Features with fixed coordinates in order to render an image graphic at specific location?

Comment: can you describe how you are drawing the polygons? may be show us some code?

Comment: Hi! I now added some code to give you a better picture on what I am trying to do.

Comment: not clear why you need a different set of rules for each filter? can you not style based on attributes in DB. For GeoReferenced icons simply add graphic to point symbolizer for your point features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now found the solution. I decided to create a new layer to render the images. The (example) code will be like this:

```
    List<SimpleFeature> list = new ArrayList<SimpleFeature>();
    SimpleFeature feature = build.buildFeature("fid1", new Object[]{ geom.point(707009.4375,243649.18750000006), "TestImage" } );
    list.add( feature );
    SimpleFeatureCollection collection = new ListFeatureCollection(cantonSchema, list);
    FeatureSource source = new CollectionFeatureSource(collection);

    StyleBuilder sb = new StyleBuilder();
    Graphic graphic = sb.createGraphic();
    URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("img/Explosion.png");
    ExternalGraphic external = sb.createExternalGraphic( url, "image/png");
    graphic.graphicalSymbols().clear();
    graphic.graphicalSymbols().add( external );
    graphic.setSize(filterFactory.literal(30));


    PointSymbolizer pointSymbolizer = styleFactory.createPointSymbolizer(graphic, null);
    pointSymbolizer.getOptions().put("maxDisplacement", "150");
    Rule rule = styleFactory.createRule();
    rule.symbolizers().add(pointSymbolizer);
    // tie this rule to the featureId
    rule.setFilter(ff2.id(feature.getIdentifier()));

    Style singleEventStyle = SLD.wrapSymbolizers(pointSymbolizer);


    Layer singeEventLayer = new FeatureLayer(source, singleEventStyle);
    map.addLayer(singeEventLayer);
```